# How to update the hours and minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQl Server 2000

Table

```
time (varchar)

2
1.5
3
5
2
2.5

...
```

I want to conver the time in datetime format like this 02:00 (HH:MM), 2.5 or 1.5 should be 02:30 hours, 01:30 Hours

Expected output

```
time (varchar)

02:00
01:30
03:00
05:00
02:00
02:30

...
```

how to do this in sql

Need sql query help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this may be much easier (you can `CAST` to `time` or `datetime`)

```
CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, n * 60, 0.0) as time)
```

But if you want a `varchar` implementation

```
LTRIM(CAST(n as int)) 
+ RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(CAST((n % 1) * 60) as int), 2)
```

Where `n` is your number.

`LTRIM` is used as a simple way to convert the numbers into `varchar`.  We `CAST` `n` to an `int` to grab the hour portion, then we get the remainder from `n` to get the remaining fraction of an hour and convert to minutes with `* 60`.  Then we `CAST` the minutes to `int` to truncate the decimal places, use `RIGHT` and pad a zero to the left to ensure that it is exactly two characters wide.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
create table t(tim varchar(10))

insert into t
VALUES('2'),('1.5'),('3'),('5'),('2'),('2.5')

select LEN(LEFT(tim,CHARINDEX('.',tim,1))),tim,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',tim,1)>0 then 
CASE WHEN LEN(LEFT(tim,CHARINDEX('.',tim,1)-1))=1 then '0'+LEFT(tim,CHARINDEX('.',tim,1)) else LEFT(tim,CHARINDEX('.',tim,1)) end +':'+cast(cast((cast(right(tim,len(tim)-CHARINDEX('.',tim,1)) as int)*60.0)/10 as int) as varchar) 
else '0'+tim+':00' end from t
```